# Add and delete Sharepoint Groups from site

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, pnp-powershell, pnp, powershell-script

Thanks for you time reading this.
We are a Technical School that's using Sharepoint 365 as way to collect files and resources. We have to open a Sharepoint to each class and I'm compiling a Powershell script to be easier...
When added a Site lets say "Class.ABC", the system also creates a group called "ClassABC@acme.org" (without the dot) and through the script I add the students to the group. I'm using PNP.Powershell. One example:

```
Add-UnifiedGroupLinks –Identity "ClassABC@acme.org" –LinkType "Members" –Links "Student.19912@acme.org"
```

The problem is this group "ClassABC@acme.org" is put in the "Members" group of the site by default, and therefore with contribute permissions. I want to change this group to "Visitors" of the site.

I've try this:

```
Add-PnPGroupMember -LoginName "ClassABC@acme.orgt" -Identity "Visitors of Class.ABC"
Remove-PnPGroupMember -LoginName "ClassABC@acme.org" -Identity "Members of Class.ABC"
```

But it didn't work as they work only with users not groups!

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Thanks a lot for your kind help. I'm not very good at Powershell, so please be gentle! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cmdlet you should use is `Set-PnPWebPermission` or `Add-SPOUser`.

Example:

```
Set-PnPWebPermission -User "ClassABC@acme.org" -AddRole "Visitor"
```

Or

```
Add-SPOUser -Site https://hasai.sharepoint.com/sites/Team -LoginName ClassABC@acme.org -Group "ClassABC Visitors"
```

References: [Set-PnPWebPermission.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/set-pnpwebpermission?view=sharepoint-ps) / [Add a user to other site collection groups.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/manage-sharepoint-users-and-groups-with-powershell?view=o365-worldwide#add-a-user-to-other-site-collection-groups)

---

**NOTE:**

The cmdlet `Add-UnifiedGroupLinks` works for managing Microsoft 365 group members only.

And the script for `Add-PnPGroupMember` should be

```
Add-PnPGroupMember -LoginName ClassABC@acme.org -Group " Class.ABC Visitors"
```

Comment: You're right! The Add-PNPGroupMember was wrong as you said!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are adding users to a **Microsoft 365 Group**, I'm afraid you may not be able to move that group from its current SPO Members group to Visitors group. However, you could change the default SPO Members group's permission from **Edit** to **Read** using the following script.

Reference [doc.microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/set-pnpgroup?view=sharepoint-ps)

```
Set-PnPGroup -Identity 'My Site Members' -SetAssociatedGroup Visitors
```

You can also accomplish the same manually.
For details, visit [this link](https://www.dontpapanic.com/blog/?p=526#:%7E:text=You%20just%20navigate%20to%20Site,Permissions%20button%20in%20the%20Ribbon.)

Comment: Thanks Matiur!
I don't want to change the permissions as I use the group for the Teacher who have the Edit permissions